# How do I get my Cocoa app to draw exactly the color specified by my designer in Sketch?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nscolorspace

My designer has specified a color to draw. When I try to draw that color in a Cocoa app, I get a resulting color that’s visibly different from the reference image as displayed by Sketch.app.

I made a small Cocoa app that draws a custom view. Here’s the interesting part of the code. Note that I am initializing the color in SRGB space.

```
class View: NSView {
    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let components : [CGFloat] = [156.0/255.0, 0, 254.0/255.0, 1]
        let color = NSColor.init(SRGBRed: components[0], green: components[1], blue: components[2], alpha: components[3])
        color.setFill()
        NSRectFill(self.bounds)
    }    
}
```

Here’s what it draws. (Nevermind the part about the cursor. And I removed the window shadow so it would be easier to review this side by side with other windows.)

[image]

And here’s the Sketch file portion:

[image]

Putting it all together, here’s a side by side of the Sketch file and the custom view, as well as Xscope loupe displaying the color value under the mouse cursor.

When hovering over Sketch file, I see this:

[image]

When hovering over my custom view, I see this:

[image]

You can see that the color value of the pixel under the black mouse cursor as read by Xscope is significantly different. The colors also look significantly different on my Retina Macbook Pro display, though interestingly, not so different in the captured screenshot PNG.

HOWEVER: so far, this was all done with default display settings and color profile “Color LCD” (the hardware is Retina Macbook Pro with its built-in display). When I manually change the display profile to “sRGB IEC61966-2.1” in OSX Settings app, and then sample the colors again with Xscope, you can see these sampled values:

[image]

And when sampling the custom view:

[image]

Most interestingly, you can see that the values sampled by Xscope on my custom view exactly match the specified values, and the color is also visually correct. But of course, I can’t make my users change their display profile.

My question: how do I make my custom view color exactly match the color in Sketch (both for visual inspection and when sampled with the Xscope loupe) with the default Color LCD display profile?

Comment: I would not necessarily assume that Sketch.app is great at preserving the color profile of an imported image file. I assume the image file has an embedded color profile. Preview.app is likely more reliable. Depending on how the designer created the file, the color swatch may be in their display's color profile, which wouldn't necessarily reproduce faithfully on another display. If they specified that the RGB values they listed are in the sRGB colorspace, then just use those. For what it's worth, #9c00fe encodes those RGB values in web color notation, which is explicitly sRGB.

Comment: The designer just drew a box in Sketch and input the color as its fill value. My job is to get the two to match on my screen (so the color will look correct to the designer and our users on their screens.)

Comment: How did the designer pick the color? Did they use the standard color picker window? In that window, on the tab which allows entering/viewing RGB values, there's a little control to pick the colorspace. If they weren't careful to pick a specific colorspace and communicate that to you, then their choice is next to useless, I'm afraid. Same with the RGB values they listed. If you can have them reproduce the process while you observe, you can maybe figure out what colorspace those RGB values are from. Or have them converted to a desired colorspace.

Comment: The designer picks the color with the Sketch integrated color picker. There is no color management in Sketch: it all seems to work in the SRGB space.

Comment: I also created a CSS style with the color code. Different browsers render it differently: Chrome behaves like Sketch in my above example, while Safari behaves like my test app. I would like my own app to work with the Chrome/Sketch model.

Comment: Sketch doesn't use a custom color picker. That's the OS X standard color picker. The question is, what did your designer do with the color picker? For example, did they use the color wheel? Just play with the RGB sliders? Etc. Then, how did they determine which RGB values to write down for you? I presume the went to the RGB sliders tab and just wrote down the values it said there. However, those values are not some universal RGB scale. They are specific to a colorspace, which can be selected with a widget on that tab. They ***may*** be sRGB, but not necessarily. You need to find out which.

Comment: In the color picker window, on the Color Sliders tab, to the left of the pop-up menu that lets you pick which sliders (e.g. Gray Scale Slider, RGB Sliders, etc.), there's a square button. It looks a bit like a color wheel and has an arrow indicating it's a pop-up button, too. In that button's pop-up menu, it indicates which colorspace the sliders' values are from/for. Device Space is what you get if you use the magnifying glass to select a color on screen. Picking a color in other parts of the window (e.g. Color Wheel) usually resets it to Generic RGB. Switching colorspace converts the values.

Comment: Are we talking about the same Sketch.app? The one I refer to is http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/, and its color picker looks like this, which I don’t think is the OS X picker: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8u6q4vfefzonb6j/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-04%20at%2018.00.08.png?dl=0

Comment: Oh. No, that's not what I thought you were talking about. I thought you were talking about Apple's [Sketch sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Sketch/Introduction/Intro.html). I thought it was weird to use that for design. The problem remains, though, that you need to know what colorspace those RGB values are relative to. And you need to know if a Sketch document preserves that information so that the color is independent of the system on which the document is created.

Comment: Color is a complicated issue and it seems that Sketch simply doesn't bother doing it correctly. The numbers it gives are probably near-useless. I suggest having the designer open the Sketch document on the original machine used to compose it; open TextEdit; in TextEdit, do Format > Font > Show Colors; select the Color Sliders tab and RGB Sliders; use the magnifying glass to sample the color from the Sketch document; use the colorspace pop-up I described to switch from Device Space to either Generic RGB or sRGB; and transcribe the resulting values. Then use those with the corresponding method.

Answer (score 0):

Just worked through this issue myself. Here's my process. Just tested on a Retina Macbook Pro.

1. Open Sketch.
2. Open Digital Color Meter  (installed on OSX)
3. Switch to 'Display in Generic RGB'
4. In menu, ensure that 'View -> Display Values -> As Decimal`
5. Mouse over your color of the artwork in sketch and note the values (e.g. 0, 150, 200)

Use that value in Cocoa:

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0/255.0 green:150/255.0 blue:200/255.0 alpha:1] set];
    NSRectFill(self.bounds);
}
```

This should work, as 'Generic RGB' is a device independent space equivalent to the 'calibrated' color space in Cocoa.

Comment: This only works if you've opened the document on the same system as the designer used to design it. If not, then your Mac is not showing the same color as the designer's when they designed it and the situation is hopeless. The designer **must** use a workflow that makes use of and preserves the color profile, which Sketch does not (last I checked). And you must use a program that respects the attached color profile when displaying images, if you're going to sample from them.

Comment: @KenThomases yes, this is absolutely true and a good point.  My workflow only guarantees a perfect translation from what the developer is seeing in Sketch to what the developer wants to see in Cocoa.